# Desempenho "where em foreach vs if"

Tags: c#, linq, desempenho, if, where

Qual dos casos teria um melhor desempenho?

```
var chaves = new list<string>();
foreach(var item in lista)
{
   if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Chave))
   {
      chaves.Add(item.Chave);
   }
}
```

Ou

```
listaValida = lista.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Chave));
foreach(var item in listaValida)
{
    chaves.Add(item.Chave);
}
```

Existe diferença de performance entre os dois casos ?

Comment: O segundo código é mais rápido e mais legível.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O 1 código foi mais rápido (porém eu acho ele bem mais feio de ler)
Segue o que utilizei para testar

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SpeedTest
{
    public class ItemChave
    {
        public string Chave { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<ItemChave> lista = new List<ItemChave>();
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "a" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "b" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "c" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "" });
            lista.Add(new ItemChave() { Chave = "d" });



            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            var chaves = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in lista)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Chave))
                {
                    chaves.Add(item.Chave);
                }
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Tempo 1 ={0}", sw.Elapsed);

            Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
            sw2.Start();

            var listaValida = lista.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Chave));
            foreach (var item in listaValida)
            {
                chaves.Add(item.Chave);
            }
            sw2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Tempo 2 ={0}", sw2.Elapsed);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A resposta certa é: depende.

O jbueno já explicou como funciona [no caso em que sua lista foi criada com base em dados disponíveis apenas no espaço de memória da aplicação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/198063/1658), i.e.: que sua aplicação montou sozinha.

Porém! O LINQ também pode ser usado para se obter dados de uma base de dados, caso você deseje abstrair-se completamente da linguagem SQL.

Se a sua lista fosse carregada em tempo real de um banco de dados, através de *Entity Framework*, a situação seria bem diferente.

Nesse caso:

```
var chaves = new list<string>();
foreach(var item in lista)
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Chave))
    {
       chaves.Add(item.Chave);
    }
}
```

Você pode ter feito o equivalente a um `SELECT` sem `WHERE`, que pode carregar milhões de registros para a memória. Daí você seleciona os registros que lhe interessam no C#. Pode ser um desperdício de recursos.

Nesse caso:

```
listaValida = lista.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Chave));
foreach(var item in listaValida)
{
    chaves.Add(item.Chave);
}
```

O LINQ gera um comando SQL mais ou menos assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE chave is not null AND LEN(chave) > 0
```

Dessa forma, você pode evitar potencialmente a carga e o trânsito de milhões de registro. Essa forma seria indiscutivelmente mais rápida para a maioria dos casos.

---

Em ambos os casos, se você usar o método `.ToList()` o seu código fica mais limpo.

Comment: Tem esse ponto tb, ainda que eu acho que ele esteja falando de uma lista em memória.

Answer (score 5):

Não tem muito mistério. Sem conhecer os detalhes de como funciona a linguagem é só medindo e fazendo uma média pra ter uma base de qual é mais rápido.

Nos meus testes, com três milhões de registros, primeiro caso foi mais rápido (`Caso1()`), levando uma média de de 40ms a cada execução, o segundo (`Caso2()`) ficou com uma média de 55ms por execução.

Usando `.ToList()` (`Caso3()`) cada execução levou uma média de 90ms.

O código que eu usei pra testar foi este:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;

public class Program 
{
    static List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        PopularLista();

        Console.WriteLine(lista.Count);

        Caso1();
        Caso2();
        Caso3();
    }

    private static void Caso1()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var chaves = new List<string>();
        foreach(var item in lista)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
            {
                chaves.Add(item);
            }
        }

        watch.Stop();
        var ms = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Caso 1: " + ms + " ms");
    }

    private static void Caso2()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var chaves = new List<string>();
        var listaValida = lista.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x));
        foreach(var item in listaValida)
        {
            chaves.Add(item);
        }

        watch.Stop();
        var ms = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Caso 2: " + ms + " ms");
    }

    private static void Caso3()
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var listaValida = lista.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();   

        watch.Stop();
        var ms = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Caso 3: " + ms + " ms");
    }

    private static void PopularLista()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 3000000; i++)
            lista.Add(i % 2 == 0 ? "Teste" : "");
    }
}
```

[Você pode rodar os testes no repl.it.](https://repl.it/HI9r/1)

Comment: Seria impossível a abstração do LINQ ser mais rápido. Só não vejo porque precisa fazer o `ToList()`.

Comment: @bigown é eu sei, mas quero achar o fonte do Linq pra ter uma base pra poder falar isso. Onde você vê os fontes do .net framework mesmo?

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/. Se bobear o `ToList()` até torna a comparação injusta pq faz o *loop* duas vezes. Só não vou afirmar porque pode ter algo que eu não saiba, mas é quase certo que será pior injustamente.

Comment: Pois é, eu pensei nisso agora pouco. Vou procurar o source e confirmar.

Comment: Agora que eu vi o código, na verdade está comparando coisas diferentes e não está usando o código dele no caso 2. Isso é injusto. Então no código está fazendo só um *loop*, mas não é bem o que ele deseja, apesar de que o resultado acabará sendo o mesmo.

Comment: Eu fiz com os dois dele e coloquei o `ToList()` como terceiro caso.

Comment: Legal pra ter um parâmetro, depois q eu vi q vc substituiu o `foreach` pelo ``Tolist()` não causando o duplo processamento. Testou na sua máquina sem mais nada rodando, especialmente VMs, Dockers e coisas do tipo? Imagino que tenha bastante memória. Hj é complicado testar sem influências externas.

Comment: Eu tava com um docker e uma VM rodando. Parei eles e testei de novo com 3M de registros. Dei uma atualizada na resposta.

Comment: Rodou algumas vezes? Foram consistentes. Tem certeza que o GC ñ entrou em ação em algum caso? :) Não estou dizendo que tem algo errado, só colocando alguns cuidados que é sempre bom ter qdo vai medir performance. Nem é tudo.

Comment: Rodei 20 vezes pra fazer a média. Só não tenho certeza se o GC "entrou em ação" ou não, como posso garantir isso?

Comment: Duvido q tenha entrado, e ñ sei se compensa, mas pode forçar uma coleta antes de cada `start` e pode usar o https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906201(v=vs.110).aspx. Mas nada garante mesmo, pra saber se rodou ou não teria q fazer um *profiling*, mas acho exagero a ñ ser q precise da informação 100% correta e q isso será muito relevante, o q está longe de ser o caso. Mas aí teria q ter outras preocupações tb.